# How to create a C# version 9.0 Application with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, c#-5.0, .net-5

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to create a `Console Application` that targets `.Net 5.0` so that I can use `C# Version 9.0`.

Although I have installed the `.Net 5.0` I am unable to select it when creating a project.

I would like to use some of the new features of `C# 9` but this requires version 5.0 of .Net as I understand it.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.8.3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the csproj and make sure it looks like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <TargetFrameworks>net5.0</TargetFrameworks>
...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see .NET 5 in the Target Frameworks for a .NET Core Application, you don't have the installation correct.  Here's what mine looks like

[image]

C# 9 is only available on .NET 5 (which is .NET Core not .NET Framework).

> C# 9.0 is supported only on .NET 5 and newer versions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

> .NET 5.0 is the next major release of .NET Core following 3.1. We
> named this new release .NET 5.0 instead of .NET Core 4.0 for two
> reasons:
>
> - We skipped version numbers 4.x to avoid confusion with .NET Framework
>   4.x.
> - We dropped "Core" from the name to emphasize that this is the main implementation of .NET going forward. .NET 5.0 supports more
>   types of apps and more platforms than .NET Core or .NET Framework.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five

Comment: I don't want .Net Core. I want a standard console application.

Comment: Unfortunately .Net Core does not meet my needs